# Contourf animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am using a for loop to calculate values at every node of 20x20 matrix and storing data in

```
MM = []
```

I want to animate the results and my code looks like this:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111) 
for i in range(60): 
    x = MM[i]  
    ax.contourf(X,Y,x, cmap = cm.hot) 
    plt.draw()                            

plt.show()
```

The problem is that it shows only MM[-1].
I have looked over the examples given here, but can't figure out how to make it work.
Thank you.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16915966/1461210, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23070305/1461210

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely due how you are running Matplotlib and what graphical [backend](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) you are using. The following example works in IPython. Note that I call [ion()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ion) to set the interactive mode to on.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.01, 0.025)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

plt.ion()
ax = plt.subplot(111) 
for i in range(1,20): 
    Z1 = plt.mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 0.5+i*0.1, 0.5, 1, 1)
    ax.contourf(x,y,Z1, cmap = plt.cm.hot) 
    plt.draw()    

plt.show()
```

The information [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/shell.html) should help you get your animation running.

Comment: still the same, although it opens a plotting screen and it loads itself for a bit, and then shows the last data.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with FuncAnimation?